# What is the basis for the idea that God is highly involved in human lives?

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-god, divine-intervention

A few days ago a family member who is religious told me about an event in her life that she thinks is a miracle. She witnessed a car wreck in front of her, and believes that it is a miracle that it was not them because they had stopped to pray beforehand. The details are not particularly important to this question.

I know many people of various religions, but I've only heard similar statements from Christians. I live in the USA so I'm wondering if this is something that is largely cultural (being the most popular religion here) or if there is something particular about Christianity that encourages this?

Are there any verses in the Bible which support this kind of hyper-involvement in your life by God?

And is there a specific movement or denomination that is particularly supportive of this idea?

Comment: I'm afraid this is neither unique to the States nor even to Chrisianity. I don't disbelieve in the miraculous either, but you should know that not everything attributed to or done in the name of Christianity actually is.

Comment: Please ask a clear question and put it in the title as The Question.

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to learn about Christianity in regards to theology, practice, rituals, and culture?

Comment: Good question, you should put it in the body of the post. Also, I would tag this differently, I don't understand the connection of the question to proselytizing.

Comment: I do not understand the point of this question. What do you mean by "cultural focus"? Also, there is this concept called "divine providence", which refers to the divine intervention in the world.

Comment: [I think this is mainly an American phenomenon, yes](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/slacktivist/2010/03/01/tf-gwfyl/).

Comment: [This question has been discussed on Meta](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4308/17789)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many Christians, and I am one of those; who believe that God knows everything, controls everything, and is everywhere simultaneously. This idea is commonly known as God being omniscient, omnipotent, and Omnipresent. To most of us that simply means that God is with his people at all times, that God knows everything and every circumstance that will take place right up until the end of time; and that he directs circumstances in order that things will happen exactly the way he wants them to right up until the end of days.

There are innumerable concepts as to how much control God uses to accomplish his goals. They range from superficial management, all the way to micro management.

Those who are prone to believe that God micro manages base that belief on:

> Matthew 10:29 through 31 NKJV  Are not two sparrows sold for a copper coin? And not one of them falls to the ground apart from your Father's will. 30  But the very hairs of your head are all numbered. 31  Do not fear therefore; you are of more value than many sparrows.

However; to think that God micro manages everything, every incident, and all events; would appear to my simple mind to take away a free will.

There are however; some incidents in which it would appear that only holy intervention could have caused some result.

To this end I will cite this incident.

I have a close friend, who was diagnosed with terminal cancer. He was given only a few months of life by several doctors. After many prayer sessions, by both he and others in the church; he returned to the doctor who originally diagnosed him with the cancer. On that visit there was no sign of cancer left, and today 10 years later he is still praising God for that healing.

Although I cannot say that I know beyond a doubt that his healing was God's work, I do believe that there is no other explanation.

Christianity, is known as faith for a reason;

Faith according to Merriam Webster; is. Latin: to trust; Greek: to persuade, to draw towards any thing, to conciliate; to believe, to obey. Belief; the assent of the mind to the truth of what is declared by another, resting on his authority and veracity, without other evidence; the judgment that what another states or testifies is the truth.

I have abbreviated this definition because it was extremely long; however; it still contains the main idea which I want to convey. That idea is that faith and free will are almost the same thing as far as Christians are concerned. One can either choose to believe or not believe. Just as one can choose to believe or not believe things that are written in the history books are other similar publications. And the depth of that belief can have a wide range.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Bye for an informative answer. It's not completely addressing my original question, but it is for the most part. I worded my original title as _"I know you don't believe in God, but..."_ and it got changed. That was mainly what I was asking, why a Christian (or perhaps other religious person) would feel obligated to try to proselytize in that way to someone which they have known for a good amount of time didn't believe.

Comment: @Phrancis since what you really want to ask is about why Christians proselytize using incidents where they feel God has intervened on their behalf. I suggest you ask it just that way, and the answers will be more in line with what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The idea that God cares about each of us individually, to the point of intervening directly in human history on our behalf (in the person of Jesus), is arguably the central concept of Christianity.

Some of the passages in the Gospels that support this idea are [John 3:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203%3A16&version=NIV) (for God so loved the world that he gave his only begotten son), the parables of [the prodigal son (a father loves even a wayward son), the widow and the lost coin (even one lost coin is valuable), the lost sheep (even one lost sheep is sought after)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2015%20&version=NIV) and [the sparrow](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2010:29&version=NIV) (even the very hairs of your head are all numbered... you are worth more than many sparrows), as well as the [Greatest Commandments](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2022:36-40&version=NIV) (love your neighbor as yourself) and [related teachings](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2013:34&version=NIV) (love each other as I have loved you) by Jesus.

It's arguable whether this should be interpreted as your relative interprets it, but it does explain why Christianity in particular is committed to the idea that God *actively* loves us *as individuals*.

Comment: Again, not an answer.  It may be right, but there is no support shown.

Comment: @AffableGeek Edited to add support.

Comment: Better. You are giving good references now

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any verses in the Bible which support this kind of hyper-involvement in your life by God?

This is the question that I am going to address here, and I think that it will point out why people might think that God touches the lives of all His people.

I am going to give instances where God intervened in the lives of people on Earth.

- Creation Genesis 1:1-31
- Created Man Genesis 1:27
- Gave Adam a companion Genesis 2:20-25
- Gave Adam the first Law Genesis 2:15-17
- Noah and the flood Genesis Chapters 6-9
- Dreams of Pharaoh and Joseph's interpretations Genesis 41
- The life of Moses

  - Being saved from death Exodus 2:1-10
  - The Burning Bush Exodus 3:2-21
  - The Dealings with Pharaoh
- Daniel in the den of lions Daniel 6:21 & 22
- Shadrach, Meshach, and Abednego saved from the furnace Daniel 3:19-26

The list goes on, but points to Divine intervention.  Whether it be by angels sent from God or from God Himself speaking to men to guide their path, this would force people to believe that God will intervene in some fashion should He find favor with them, or love them.

As far as being a cultural belief, I think that it would be a Christian belief, if you consider being Christianity a culture.  I also believe though that any religion that is based on the Old Testament would follow suit as well. I have only listed occurrences from the Old Testament, and I believe that the Old Testament still holds true to this day.

> Do not think that I came to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I did not come to abolish but to fulfill. For truly I say to you, until heaven and earth pass away, not the smallest letter or stroke shall pass from the Law until all is accomplished.…

Matthew 5:17

The Old Testament is often referred to as the Law, and Jesus said He did not come to abolish the things that occurred during that time frame but to fulfill these things.

Comment: So, I'm a Christian, and I believe everything you say - but keep the OP audience in mind. You've given me a list of 11 incidents that at the very least took place over the course of 3500 years (4004BC - 587BC). Worse, secularists would discount every one of those as tradition rather than fact. I would heartily.  I'm already convinced that you're right - how do you convince the skeptic?

Answer (score -1):

God certainly is involved in every single detail. And we are called to not only acknowledge and praise Him for that fact, but to seek His intervention in every circumstance no matter how big or small.

> "In all your ways acknowledge Him,
>   And He shall direct your paths."
>   - Proverbs 3:6

---

> "Do not be anxious about anything. Instead, in every situation, through prayer and petition with thanksgiving, tell your requests to God."
>   - Phillippians 4:6

---

> "Rejoice always,pray without ceasing, give thanks in all circumstances; for this is the will of God in Christ Jesus for you." - 1 Thessalonians 5:16-18

I wonder, if you were truly a Christian and not just someone who used to profess to be one, then why have you forgotten the miracles that God performed in your life when He saved you? The real Christian experiences the real Spirit of God, and while it is faith, it is a tangible faith that proves itself to the born-again believer. If you have never experienced that, then do not write off Christ. Seek Him if you desire God.

Comment: -1: `...Why have you forgotten the miracles that God performed in your life when He saved you?`: I was born in the Disco Era. Which miracles have been performed since then?

Comment: There are miracles performed every day.

Comment: @TaylorDBarrett I appreciate you attempting an answer to my question. I can't think of anything I would deem miraculous which happened while I was a Christian, so it rings a bit hollow when I read _"why have you forgotten the miracles that God performed in your life"_ ...

Comment: @Phrancis If you didn't consider your conversion itself to be a miracle, then many would argue that you were not a Christian. Most Christian groups acknowledge that the salvation of a person from their bondage to sin and death is only possible with God, ergo, conversion is a miracle. If while you claimed to be a Christian you also denied that your conversion was a miracle, then either you were deceived or else deceitful, but in neither case would you be considered to be a faithful convert to Christianity.

Comment: @Andrew: Have you ever heard of circular reasoning? https://www.google.com/search?q=circular+reasoning&oq=circular+reasoning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j5j0.4860j0j4&client=ms-android-att-us&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @JimG. Yes. How do you suggest the reasoning is faulty?

Comment: @Andrew in OP's original unedited post, he mentioned that he is now an athiest... so, that logic is... Please remember that this is not a "Christian" site, but a site about Christianity. It's a subtle but important difference.